# Spinnaker clouddriver doesn't start

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

After Spinnaker deployment on EC2, clouddriver doesn't start. tried the same on local machine and the result is the same. Trying to run 1.6.1 on ubuntu 16.04.
I am using s3 as storage aws as cloudprovider.
After deployment spinnaker UI is accesable, when creating new application the windows hangs and error message appears in browser's console regarding localhost:8084/ credentials and 7002 port.
tried to send curl request to localhost:7002 from the server, but connection refused. 7002 port isn't being listened but all other services ports are. clouddriver start and then enters failed state (for about after 30 seconds).
For deployment I've followed this guide on official website.
Also I can't find logs of services in /var/log/spinnaker/any service/ path, there are logs only in /var/log/spinnaker/halyard/ path.
All policies/roles/users have been made in aws properly as described in official setup guide. double checked. Still facing issue.
Maybe I am missing anything?
Here is the error from browser console when trying to create new application

```
GET http://localhost:8084/credentials?expand=true 500 () angular.js:14525 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException","message":"retrofit.RetrofitError: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:7002","status":500,"timestamp":1523484058259},"status":500,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"http://localhost:8084/credentials","cache":true,"params":{"expand":true},"timeout":65000,"headers":{"X-RateLimit-App":"deck","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"withCredentials":true},"statusText":""} undefined
```

Have done some tests later. Here are results.

1deployed spinnaker without s3 storage and any cloud provider - clouddriver works
2added s3 as persistent storage - clouddriver works again. Opened UI created dummy project and saw that files have been created in the s3 bucket under front50 folder. everything fine.
3added aws configurations - created user in aws, and ran this command with appropriate changes

```
hal config provider aws edit --access-key-id ${ACCESS_KEY_ID} \ --secret-access-key
```

and ran this command with appropriate changes

```
hal config provider aws account add $AWS_ACCOUNT_NAME \ --account-id ${ACCOUNT_ID} \ --assume-role role/spinnakerManaged
```

after checking aws configs with hal config provider aws the value of defaultAssumeRole=0
and after hal deploy apply again clouddriver doesn't start and I cannot create an application from UI. the window loads infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

This is the option for dev spinnaker. `localdebian` type never worked for me as it contains extra dependencies.

Please use a Kubernetes cluster for the installation or user [Minnaker](https://github.com/armory/minnaker) for quick PoC of OSS. It runs on a K3S cluster.